# Why is my Cursor empty after this SQLite database query?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, cursor

startTime and endTime are strings in the format "2011-07-22 13:00:00".
The following code makes myCursor.moveToFirst() return false.

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM myData WHERE 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime) >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '"+startTime+"') 
    AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime) <= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '"+endTime+"')";
Cursor myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

However, when I go into the sqlite3 shell and type

```
SELECT * FROM myData WHERE 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime) >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '2011-07-22 13:00:00') 
    AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime) <= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '2011-07-22 13:02:00');
```

it prints out what I need. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing your `moveToFirst()` call?

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM myData WHERE 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime) >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '"+startTime+"') 
    AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime) <= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '"+endTime+"')";
Cursor myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
myCursor.moveToFirst();  //
```

Comment: No, I have that, and it returns false; I only posted the relevant two lines.